# React JSX: is it normal that re-render of parent component remounts child component?

Tags: reactjs, resize, react-router, jsx, rerender

In the root component of my React App, I have this:

```
class App extends Component {
...
  ComponentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener('resize', this.handleResize, false);
  }
  handleResize{
    this.parentSize = {height: window.innerWidht - this.node.offsetLeft ..., width: ...};
    this.forceUpdate();
  }
  render() {
    <div ref="e=>this.node=e}>
      <ChildComponent parentSize={this.ParentSize} />
    </div>
  }
}
```

I noticed that when App component re-renders, either through setState or forceUpdate(), the child component is actually remounted (so componentWillUnmount, componentWillMount, componentDidMount is called every update). The behavior I would expect is that only the render function of the Child component is called again. I recently upgraded to React-router 4.x, so I am not sure if it is related to this.

Can someone tell me if this is by design? Having my componentDidMount called multiple times causes some issues as I try to fetch data in it, and I don't want to be doing that expensive operation multiple times after another during a resize.

UPDATE:

I have found the likely cause of this issue. I have multiple nested Components and since it's hard to post the entire project, it's sometimes hard to post the actual code that is causing the issue. But I think this is it:

```
return (
  <div className="app-view" style={style} ref={el=>this.node=el}>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path='/' component={() => <Home store={store} />} />
      <Route path='*' component={Error404} />
    </Switch>
  </div>
);
```

Here I am trying to pass props to the components in a route (React-router 4.x)
I do this by providing a function that creates the Home page, which likely is re-recreating the Home page at every render.

So the question becomes, how to pass the props without the recreation of the pages at every render inside a Route?

Comment: can you add your ChildComponent code.It should not call componentDidMount multiple times unless you navigate.

Comment: Likely culprit is the child is receiving an updated set of props or state which throws the re-render. Share your Child Component please.

Comment: See updated: () => <Home ..> inside the route is causing the issue I think.
The child component code was replaced by a dummy that does nothing but log the life cycle methods to console, to debug the issue. So the issue is in the parent component and I believe it's in the updated section of my question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've confirmed the issue to be related to my recent React-Router 4.x upgrade.
The docs for React-Router:

When you use component (instead of render or children, below) the router uses React.createElement to create a new React element from the given component. That means if you provide an inline function to the component attribute, you would create a new component every render. This results in the existing component unmounting and the new component mounting instead of just updating the existing component. When using an inline function for inline rendering, use the render or the children prop (below).

Thanks for everyone's support.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me from the code you posted that the functions you mention both alter `this.parentSize` and then rerender the page. Event if the value of `this.parentSize` does not change, its value is being reassigned:

```
this.parentSize = {height: window.innerWidht - this.node.offsetLeft ..., width: ...};
```

If my understanding is correct, then it is necessary for the child component to re render, because the information used to generate the component has changed, therefore the component must be re rendered to account for the props change. It may well be the case that there are no changes to the DOM, so the page does not change visually.

You can check what operations are being performed by using the Perf add on and using the `printOperations` function.

One way to prevent the re render would be to use `shouldcomponentupdate` and return false when you do not want the component to re render

EDIT:

Based on the info provided above, it seems you want to update a child component by calling a function on the parent component, but do not want the parent to re render?

If this is the case, you can do this by doing the following:

The first time the child component renders, you call `componentWillMount`, and get the prop you want to be able to control from the parent, and save it as state, like this:

```
componentWillMount() {
  const { myProp } = this.props;
  this.setState({
    myProp
  });
}
```

Then in this component you make a function called something like:

```
updateMyProp(newProp) {
  this.setState({
    myProp: newProp
  })
}
```

From then on, this variable is controlled by `state` and not `props`

Next, on the parent page, the component needs to have a `ref` variable, like this:

```
<Yourcomponent
  ref={d=> this.componentName = d}
  ...
/>
```

Now, from the parent page you can call the `updateMyProp` function by doing the following:

```
this.componentName.updateMyProp(someNewValue)
```

This will cause the child component to renreder, but not the parent

I hope I have understood your question properly!!

Comment: See updated: () => <Home ..> inside the route is causing the issue I think.